# why singularity can not find my executable?

Tags: singularity-container

I try to bundle ImageJ software in a light singularity container. To do so, I built the following def file:

```
Bootstrap: docker
From: alpine

%post
    apk update
    apk add wget
        
    cd /usr/local/bin
    
    wget https://wsr.imagej.net/distros/linux/ij153-linux64-java8.zip
    unzip ij153-linux64-java8.zip
    rm ij153-linux64-java8.zip
    
%runscript
    exec /usr/local/bin/ImageJ/ImageJ
```

Everything runs OK at build time but when I run the sif file I get:

```
/bin/sh: /usr/local/bin/ImageJ/ImageJ: not found
```

When inspecting the container with a singularity shell command, the path exists yet. Would you know what is going wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's linked against glibc, but Alpine [uses `musl libc`](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_newbie#Feature_Differences). You can try to [run glibc on Alpine](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Running_glibc_programs), but if Alpine is not a hard requirement the simplest solution is to use a different OS for the base image.